# "on" preventDefault 

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

What am I missing here?

Please note: jQuery MOBILE is used

- [DEMO using preventDefault](http://plungjan.name/test/jqmob_def.html)
- [DEMO using return false](http://plungjan.name/test/jqmob_false.html)

If I use preventDefault the page loads as if I had just links and no script, when I change to return false (which I always used to use on the plain JS onclick event handler), it works as expected. 
I have already looked through other posts and all use .click and all suggest preventDefault.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#leftdiv a").on("click",function(e) {
    $("#rightDiv").load(this.href);
    return false; // I was sure preventDefault would work
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="leftdiv" style="position:absolute;padding-right:5%; overflow:scroll;">
<a href="page1.htm">Launch page 1</a><br />
<a href="page2.htm">Launch page 2</a>
</div>

<div id="rightDiv" style="padding-left:30%"></div>
```

Comment: unlike `return false` which usually is placed at the end, try using  `e.preventDefault()` before everything else.

Comment: @Joseph sure it is usually placed at the end, it is the last pice of code that would get executed. It does not depend where you put the preventDefault call.

Comment: _"it works as expected"_ - could you please be a bit clearer about what "as expected" means in this case? What is your desired behaviour? And can you show the exact code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

didn't work ?

- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

> ```
> $('a').on("click",function(e){
>      //do something
>      e.preventDefault();
> });
> ```

Putting `e.preventDefault();` on the top or on the end of your code does not matter normally. There is also the method `e.stop()` I guess. But why don't you stick with `return false;` when it's working for you ?

**From jQuery mobile documentation:**

> Canceling an elements default click behavior
>
> Applications can call preventDefault() on a vclick event to cancel an
>   element's default click behavior. On mouse based devices, calling
>   preventDefault() on a vclick event equates to calling preventDefault()
>   on the real click event during the bubble event phase. On touch based
>   devices, it's a bit more complicated since the actual click event is
>   dispatched about 300ms after the vclick event is dispatched. For touch
>   devices, calling preventDefault() on a vclick event triggers some code
>   in the vmouse plugin that attempts to catch the next click event that
>   gets dispatched by the browser, during the capture event phase, and
>   calls preventDefault() and stopPropagation() on it. As mentioned in
>   the warning above, it is sometimes difficult to match up a touch event
>   with its corresponding mouse event because the targets can differ. For
>   this reason, the vmouse plugin also falls back to attempting to
>   identify a corresponding click event by coordinates. There are still
>   cases where both target and coordinate identification fail, which
>   results in the click event being dispatched and either triggering the
>   default action of the element, or in the case where content has been
>   shifted or replaced, triggering a click on a different element. If
>   this happens on a regular basis for a given element/control, we
>   suggest you use click for triggering your action.

```
function() {
  return false;
}

// IS EQUAL TO

function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

**Source:** http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

It also seems that `.on()` isn supported also as document.ready is not supported

**Source:** http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: @mplungjan I have edited my answer. Seems like there is no real way around that

Comment: Okay I did, but why aren't you using return false; when it's working ?

Comment: Thanks. Seems I have found a weird behaviour. It works in normal browser when I use return false - now I will test mobile. I have been told here at SO MANY times to use preventDefault so I wanted to :)

Comment: Do you happen to know why the page does not seem to finish loading on iPhone safari? The return false works

Comment: Hi EvilP! You seem to be the right man to answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669312/mouse-event-still-fired-on-touch-event-even-with-preventdefault-set?noredirect=1#comment38245804_24669312 Could you help me?

Comment: Hey @Garavani sorry mate I'm not into mobile jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This might provide a solution, but I lack information to explain why.
I recently came across the issue where preventDefault was not working in similar code, and the issue lies in delegating from `$(document) vs $('body')` try the following:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" id="test1">Test 1</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" id="test2">Test 2</a>
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#test1', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hi 1');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#test2', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hi 2');
    });
</script>
```

This does not happen however with jQuery 3.2.1, I can only confirm this is an issue with 2.1.7

Comment: how does this answer the question when you cant even explain why?