# jQuery click events not working in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css, click, transform

> **Second update:** Looks like one of my functions (resetFigures) was preventing the event handler, so moving that to the end of the bind function sorted it out.
>
> **Update:** I realized after some basic testing that the click events were registering, it's just that the box fails to flip when tapped.

I have the basic aesthetic functionality of my site working in Chrome and Firefox, but it refuses to behave properly on iOS (test on iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1 and iPad with iOS 4.3.5).

You can view the site and of course the scripts (main.js) here: http://bos.rggwebdesigns.com/

I've read that iOS doesn't really handle jQuery click events properly, but I'm struggling to figure out a fix. A couple threads here on Stack Overflow mentioned the live() method, but implementing it like follows (as well as adding `onclick=""` to the clickable elements) didn't seem to work:

```
$('.card').live('click touchstart', function() {
        var figure = $(this).children('.back');
        var button = figure.find('.button');
        var column = $(this).parents().eq(1);
        $('.column').removeAttr('style');
        column.css('z-index', 2000);
        resetFigures();
        if(flipCard(this)){
            swoosh.pause();
            swoosh.currentTime = 0;
            swoosh.play();
        }
    });
```

I also came across this interesting workaround project: http://aanandprasad.com/articles/jquery-tappable/.
However, I had no luck with that either:

```
$('.card').tappable(function() {
        var figure = $(this).children('.back');
        var button = figure.find('.button');
        var column = $(this).parents().eq(1);
        $('.column').removeAttr('style');
        column.css('z-index', 2000);
        resetFigures();
        if(flipCard(this)){
            swoosh.pause();
            swoosh.currentTime = 0;
            swoosh.play();
        }
    });
```

Also, please correct me if I've been mislead, but according to this site, 3D transforms are supported in iOS with the appropriate prefixes: http://caniuse.com/transforms3d

Comment: What's the issue you are seeing?

Comment: 1) live is replaced by on. 2) on also has issues as I found out a while ago:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698003/on-preventdefault

Comment: @Alexander Tapping the boxes on iOS has no effect aside from the hover state.

Comment: Here is a pretty good summary about the issue at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

Answer (score 256):

There is an issue with iOS not registering click/touch events bound to elements added after DOM loads.

While PPK has this advice: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html

I've found this the easy fix, simply add this to the css:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: wow... how is this real?! Safari done gone done it this time. This Quirksblog article clears it up further: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/10/click_event_del_1.html

Comment: This absolutely saved me a TON of time. How would one know to try something like this? Apple has to get this together. They probably won't but gee wiz -__-

Comment: WTF!? I'm wondering why click events don't work in IOS in a phonegap app using jquery .on(). I add cursor:pointer to a class and walla! This is ridiculous but it works. This is a 5 year old topic.

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me, but it's weird it's a thing in the first place xD I  tried binding all future events on click and tap but wouldn't work on iOS until I did cursor: pointer fix.

Comment: A few years ago in some Apple office: "Let's depend on a css value to decide whether we should register a click event or not". Genius!

Comment: After despairing over my script for hours, frantically trying to work out where I did something wrong to cause a simple button to not work on iOS devices, I found this through DuckDuckGo, think "this can't work", try it anyway because desperate, and it actually works. This messes with my brain.

Comment: Apply `cursor: pointer;` to the element you want to listen to its `listen` event

Comment: July 2018. This is still the solution. I don't think however, this is a bug but a design decision by iOS. For whatever reason, they think it's a good idea for CSS to influence the JavaScript behaviour.

Comment: If you are using tag `<a>`, you can also add **href** attribute into the tag.
`<a class="card">click here</a>` => `<a class="card" href="javascript:;">click here</a>`.

Comment: It might be crazy posting this in 2023, but for me, this solution is still not working on iOS 16.4.1 both Safari and Chrome, with jQuery 3.7.0.

Answer (score 58):

Recently when working on a web app for a client, I noticed that any click events added to a non-anchor element didn't work on the iPad or iPhone.  All desktop and other mobile devices worked fine - but as the Apple products are the most popular mobile devices, it was important to get it fixed.

Turns out that any non-anchor element assigned a click handler in jQuery must either have an onClick attribute (can be empty like below):

```
onClick=""
```

OR

The element css needs to have the following declaration:

```
cursor:pointer
```

Strange, but that's what it took to get things working again!
source:http://www.mitch-solutions.com/blog/17-ipad-jquery-live-click-events-not-working

Comment: so so weird. a{cursor:pointer;} worked for me

Comment: `* {
    /* To receive click events on iOS */
    cursor: pointer;    
}
`

Comment: Thanks. Adding `onClick=""` to my `<div>` which have a jQuery onClick handler worked perfectly. It was working everywhere but Safari iOS before adding this onClick attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the tap event, the click does not exist on mobile safari or in the UIWbview.
You can also use this [polyfill](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) ,to avoid the 300ms delay when a link is touched.

Comment: I tried implementing bind(), with and without jQuery Mobile for 'tap' and 'vclick', but it didn't work. Is it possible that the hover pseudo-element is interfering since on iOS a tap on an element with `:hover` defined is the equivalent of mouseover?

Comment: I don't know about the hover sorry

Comment: It's fine. It was simply a matter of making sure every `:hover` selector was preceded by `.no-touch`. Still doesn't fix the event handling.