# Custom jQuery Slider does not work on iOS 7 Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I am working on a mobile site, my first, and I am facing strange problems. I have created a custom jQuery slider with left and right buttons. I have tried it on my Android's own browser, Firefox and Chrome for Android. It works fine, as it is supposed to.

When I gave the work to my client he said it doesn't work on iPhone for which it is originaly intended. I was confused as how this is possible, as it worked flawlessly on my Android. So I asked my friend for his iPhone 4S with iOS7 and opened up the site. To my surprise, the slider did not work. I took out my phone and opened it on my Firefox, it worked!

Why is this so? If it is working on Android, shouldn't it be working on iOS too? And how can I solve it?

Regards

Comment: Would an example page or code be possible?

Comment: Here is the link: [link](http://www.mblistings.com/mob/listings.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know why this happens. By default, iOS Safari doesn't allow everything to be **"clickable"**. This means you need to make it `cursor: pointer` via CSS to make it **"clickable".**

I have got my answer from here: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios#answer-17490775) tell is why this happens. Read it!

Regards