# Website jquery click not work on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I trigger a click event when clicking on another button using `jQuery(".Classname").click()`, but it is not working using Safari on iPhone.

Example:

```
jQuery(".button1").click(function(){
  jQuery(".button2").click();
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

try use  [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

```
jQuery(".button1").click(function(){
  jQuery(".button2").trigger("click");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS fix to your button,

```
.button2 {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Consider this is an tip; if the element is not bound using `$.click()` use the DOM object like

```
jQuery(".button1").click(function(){
  jQuery(".button2")[0].click(); // or .get(0).click();
})
```