# jQuery not firing tap/touchstart events in Private Browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, mobile-safari

My code is listening to the `touchstart` event on the `.header` div:

```
$('.header').bind('touchstart', function() {
  console.log('Rock and roll.');
)};
```

This event fires across all devices and browsers, but there seems to be a problem with Safari on iPhone 6 in Private Browsing mode. This works on the same device if Private Browsing is switched off.

I tried the common tips:

```
<div class="header" onClick="">
```

and adding

```
cursor: pointer;
```

but the problem persists. Do you guys know of a workaround?

**UPDATE:** this is related to Private browsing in general and is not specific to any device type. Same thing happens when browsing in Incognito mode on Chrome on desktop.

Comment: Am not addressing the problem but what `onClick=""` is doing ?

Comment: Some users suggest it worked for them http://stackoverflow.com/a/27938334/3678689

Comment: Restart the device and test again.. Very weird problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common issue with private browsing : if you use local storage it will raise an exception & halt javascript execution. This is probably why your click events are not fired.

Comment: You're right, my friend! We solved the issue in the meantime and the reason for it was exactly that.

Comment: @Creaforge does this issue exist when using another browser on the same device?