# Click event doesnt work in safari mobile for some HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-safari

In my web app, there is a separate navbar for mobile devices. I want this navbar to collapse when the menu button is clicked or anywhere else in the site is clicked. It already works in any mobile browser but not it safari mobile (In safari also, for home page it works but not in other pages). In other pages, there are some html generated dynamically. It seems that the click event doesn't work for those content. I'd really appreciate a solution for this problem. the code is as follows. I've tried 'body', $(document), window instead of $('html'). It doesn't for them also.

```
$('html').click(function(event) {
            var clickover = $(event.target);
var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               
var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
    $navbar.collapse('hide');
}
        });
```

I've also tried what is mentioned in [Fixing jQuery Click Events for the iPad](http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/). But the code mentioned in there doesn't trigger at all. The code I've tried for this as belows.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$('body').bind(event, function(e) {
            var clickover = $(event.target);
var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               
var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
    $navbar.collapse('hide');
}
```

}

I'd really appreciate an answer for my question (I was working on this for more than a day but didn't find a solution).

Comment: $(body).on('click', 'selector', function() {})

Comment: $("body").click(function(event){alert("test")}); should work. If it doesn't, there might be a complete different error that breaks your script and that you're overlooking.

Answer (score 10):

Anyway I finally found a solution. The reason was, iPhone Safari doesnt support event delegation. What my initial requirement was to trigger the click event when the body of the HTML is clicked. Anyway the issue was only occurring on Safari mobile and the reason I found was, Safari doesn't support event delegation for the click event. I solved it by adding below code in the body CSS.

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Thre resources I got the answer were,
[Click event delegation on the iPhone](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html)

and

[jQuery click events not working in iOS : Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006333/4089799)

And Dohab, Thank you for your answer too.

Comment: This is fundamental to desinging website, how can they choose not to implement it. I don't know about you, but when I browse the internet, and I don't constantly rapidly press the screen in random pleaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div container for the entire page, and bind it to a click event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>If you click anywhere. I will hide</p>
        ...
        ...

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```