# Angular 4/5 material raised button with input file

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am working on a angular application, currently to upload a file I am using this :

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
</label>
<button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFiles"
    (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

with methods on my .ts file, it is working well.

I want to upgrade this to material angular components raised button like that right now :

```
<button mat-raised-button>
    <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
</button>

<button mat-button disabled [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

the disabled button is doing well but the input file part doesnt work , it prints baddly and does not open a file folder search window. any ideas?

Comment: you can't place an input of type file on a button, instead create the button to tricker the input file, lemme file an example via answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Won't advise using input field within a button, better you hide the file input and then a button to trigger it. The below example will show a minimal example of it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}} is for Uploading</h2>
    </div>

    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openInput()">
        Select File to Upload
    </button>

<input id="fileInput" hidden type="file" (change)="fileChange($event.target.files)" >

<button mat-button [disabled]="!ourFile" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>

  `
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  ourFile: File; // hold our file

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  /**
   * this is used to trigger the input
   */ 
  openInput(){ 
    // your can use ElementRef for this later
    document.getElementById("fileInput").click();
  }

  fileChange(files: File[]) {
    if (files.length > 0) {
      this.ourFile = files[0];
    }
  }


   /**
   * this is used to perform the actual upload
   */
   upload() {
    console.log('sending this to server', this.ourFile);
  }


}
```

Check this [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/sOhqF1?p=preview)

With the above example, you should be able to style your button without distorting HTML semantics

Comment: FYI, I don't think this event delegation works on Safari Mobile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243513/click-event-doesnt-work-in-safari-mobile-for-some-html-content