# How can i bind click event on "div" inside input on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I have html code like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
    <div class="error">Error here!</div>
</div>
```

With css this div block positions inside input by `position: absolute`.
When I open page on mobile phone, such as iPhone 5S Chrome Browser, click on this div focus it and I can delete it by click delete button on keyboard.

And when I bind click event on this div, on desktop browsers it is working, but on mobile browsers not working.

On desktop browsers no such problem.

Comment: Please include all the javascript you've written as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios possible duplicate?

Comment: For ios devices sometimes click event doesn't work,try using "touchstart" event along with click event

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU, guys!) it is working with onClick attribute in div)