# Click event jquery on safari mobile

Tags: jquery, touch, mobile-safari, jquery-click-event

The jquery click event doesn't work in mobile safari.

I tried the "curson: pointer", also downgrade/upgrad jquery version  but nothing work.

https://codepen.io/larsen1982/pen/yWYNLj

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
```

This is the jquery:
http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

In desktop, ipad and Android smarthpone browsers the code work fine.
In chrome and safari mobile (iphone) the buttons don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click events not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is iPhones don't raise click events. They raise "touch" events. Adding in the following code works.

```
function touchHandler(event){
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

    switch(event.type)
    {
       case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
       case "touchmove":  type = "mousemove"; break;        
       case "touchend":   type = "mouseup"; break;
       default: return;
    }

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, 
                          first.screenX, first.screenY, 
                          first.clientX, first.clientY, false, 
                          false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
```

Comment: Your solution work in chrome mobile (iphone) but not in safari mobile.

Comment: Do you know some trick for safari mobile?
Can be the <input> tag the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `touchstart`:

```
$(".next").on('touchstart click', function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: I feel like you have further issues in your code. It's a pretty simple task.

Comment: Still doesn't work