# mouse event still fired on touch event even with preventDefault set

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, mouseevent, preventdefault

is there anything I misunderstood here? I often use code like the following in my site that I want to work either for desktop and iPad device:

```
$("#someElement")
    .on( "mousemove", function(e) {         
        alert ( "I am still here" );
        // undesired code for ipad here
    } )
    .on( "touchmove", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // only desired code for ipad use here
    } );
```

I read in many places that the e.preventDefault should kill the mouse events attached. And that the touch events are elaborated in the first place. Yet, I now recognized that the alert is still triggered on my ipad. Why? Any hints on that? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I realized that when I put 'touchstart' instead of 'touchmove' the e.preventDefault() works in the predicted way. Come on, guys, some ideas!

Comment: Look at my answer may be it useful for you to make a simple code

Comment: Thank you for that! I will keep it in mind. Seems cool. But still: Is my thinking with e.preventDefault() wrong? Just for deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Check with user agent for ipad.simply use trenary operator for more simple code

```
var isIPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

$("#someElement").on(((isIPad)? "touchmove" : "mousemove" ), 
                         ((isIPad)? gotoIpad : gotoOthers ));

function gotoIpad() {

      alert("I am ipad");
}

function gotoOthers() {

      alert("I am not ipad");
}
```

Comment: This is an idea, but I’d like to always use the original touch events instead of the mouse events. And the code above would keep my code overall more simple.

Comment: Sorry I posted my comment to the wrong answer: Thank you for that! I will keep it in mind. Seems cool. But still: Is my thinking with e.preventDefault() wrong? Just for deeper understanding.

Comment: Browser detection is a bad idea since a few years https://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

try this  user agent

```
    var isTouch = /iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

            if(isTouch ){
            $("#someElement").on( "touchmove", function(e) {
                       // only desired code for ipad use here
                } );
            }
     else{
            $("#someElement")
                .on( "mousemove", function(e) {         
                    alert ( "I am still here" );
                    // undesired code for ipad
                });
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, too. Ok. So you say that I actually misunderstood the e.preventDefault() behaviour? And that I HAVE to go with if? :-(

Comment: And I also read somewhere that the user agent solution is (even more in future) not the best solution for there are (will be) devices with either mouse AND touch sensibility.

Comment: Browser detection is a bad idea since many years https://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html